# JBoss 7 Memory Configuration for 4G Memory, 64-bit

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I use the following memory setting in `standalone.con.bat` in `JBoss 7.1.1 Final`.

`set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:MaxHeapSize=512M"`

My Production Server can available over 4G or above. But, I cannot start the server. The over 70 users  can access with uploaded file concurrently.

**Error :**

```
 Error occurred during initialization of VM
 Incompatible minimum and maximum heap sizes specified
```

How can I set large memory?
I am not sure this setting is suitable solution between the users and sever specification.
Any body suggest to me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
-Xmx2048M
-XX:MaxHeapSize=512M
```

And you set 1024M as the minimum heap size (`-Xms1024M`).

You specify the max heap size *twice*, and the JVM takes the latest one it finds. And of course, 1024M min and 512M max makes no sense... Hence the error message. You probably didn't mean `MaxHeapSize` but something else?

A simple test program:

```
public static void main(final String... args)
{
    // Prints out the max heap size of the running JVM
    System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the underlying JVM is 32-bit. You can not really set 4GB as maximum heap size for 32 bit JVM using -Xmx JVM heap options.

Read more: http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2013/04/what-is-maximum-heap-size-for-32-bit-64-JVM-Java-memory.html

Comment: Nope... Simpler than that.

Comment: Check out this link as well :http://javarevisited.blogspot.nl/2012/12/invalid-initial-and-maximum-heap-size.html

Answer (score 1):

The configuration for standalone is in the configuration file: bin/appclient.conf.bat

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M"
```

Answer (score 0):

set

"JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Xms2048m -Xmx16096m"

Comment: You can set min and max value by doing a load test

Comment: That is not the problem here.

Comment: The answer doesn't make sense.